# A command line option has enabled the security manager

Tags: java, arrays, runtime-error

I'm writing code in **Leetcode**to find next greater element in an circular array using stack. When I'm using <= its throwing an error "A command line option has enabled the security manager" . the error is inside the second for loop `while(st.peek()<=nums[j] && !st.isEmpty()){ st.pop();`
}

```
class Solution {
    public int[] nextGreaterElements(int[] nums) {
        
        int [] dupArr = new int[nums.length];
        int[] newArr = new int[nums.length];
        
        Stack<Integer> st = new Stack<>();
        
        for(int i=nums.length-1;i>0;i--){
            if(i==nums.length-1)
                st.push(nums[i]);
            else{
                if(nums[i]>st.peek()){
                    st.pop();
                    st.push(nums[i]);
                }
                else
                    st.push(nums[i]);
            }
        }
        for(int j=nums.length-1;j>=0;j--){
            while(st.peek()<=nums[j] && !st.isEmpty()){
                st.pop();
            }
            if(st.isEmpty())
                newArr[j] = -1;
            else{
                newArr[j] = st.peek();
                st.push(nums[j]);
            }
        }
        return newArr;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`A command line option has enabled the security manager`, that is an unknown issue with Leetcode, not your code.

I suppose the problem with `<=` is that the condition should be reverse. You will get a NPE. You must first check if the stack is empty. If not, peek will return null.

```
  while(!st.isEmpty() && st.peek()<=nums[j]){
```

NB. The rest runs fine here with local JDK.